# Hibernate str() function using Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

How can I use HQL str() function which is using for converting numeric value to readable string with Criteria API?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you won't need str() function with Criteria API, since you can first convert numerics into Strings with API functions like: Integer.toString() then set as Parameter like;

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.like("age", Integer.toString(age) ) )
    .list();
```